# multiple echo json_encode from php script to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I would like to create something like "steps processing" in php and jquery (ajax). I have so far that code:

```
var steps = ["step1", "step2", "step3"];

$.ajax({                                             
    method: "POST",                                  
    url: "test_steps.php",       
    data: {steps: steps},                            
    dataType: "json",                                
    success: function(response) {                    
        console.log(response);
    },
});
```

and in php something like:

```
$steps = $_POST['steps'];                   
                                        
if (isset($steps['step1'])) {               
    if ($test->do_some_function1()) {       
        echo json_encode("step1 - success");
    }                                       
    else {                                  
        echo json_encode("step1 - fail");   
    }                                       
}                                           
                                        
if (isset($steps['step2'])) {               
    if ($test->do_some_function2()) {       
        echo json_encode("step2 - success");
    }                                       
    else {                                  
        echo json_encode("step2 - fail");   
    }                                       
}                                           
                                        
if (isset($steps['step3'])) {               
    if ($test->do_some_function3()) {       
        echo json_encode("step3 - success");
    }                                       
    else {                                  
        echo json_encode("step3 - fail");   
    }                                       
}                                           
                                        
exit;
```

In final solution I want to have it in some kid of modal, all steps with statuses. But at the beginning I would like to wait for them and get all of them in console log, one by one. How to achieve that? Let's say:

```
step1 - success
step2 - success
step3 - fail
```

As for now I get an error and all messages from PHP in error message. So it seems that I am not able to wait for all `echo json_encode` calls.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want each step to be executed separately and get feedback one by one, then each step will need to be sent in its own individual ajax request. Because to get a response from php, you have to wait for the whole script to finish

Comment: Rather than `isset($steps['step1'])` you're probably wanting `in_array('step1', $steps)`

Comment: `As for now I get an error`...for future reference if you get an error, always tell us exactly what it is. Clearly that is a significant detail relating to your problem. Rob Eyre has probably figured out the cause already, but you shouldn't assume we can always guess - and anyway if you already know the error, why should we spend the time to work it out again? See also [ask].